# python: how to run local code on cluster of remote servers?

Tags: python, distributed-computing

I'm basically looking for something like picloud.com (shut down last year) but that is able to run on my own cluster of servers.

I'd imagine some kind of server running on each of the grunt work servers and when a python code is run on my main server, it should send the job to a work server that is not "filled".

The load balancing should come at a later stage, right now what I need is a way to run local python code on the remote server I define.

Comment: how the hell is offtopic?

Comment: Someone probably marked it off topic because you are asking for a tool that lets you do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try [RPyC](http://rpyc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

From the site:
RPyC (pronounced as are-pie-see), or Remote Python Call, is a transparent python library for symmetrical remote procedure calls, clustering and distributed-computing. RPyC makes use of object-proxying, a technique that employs python’s dynamic nature, to overcome the physical boundaries between processes and computers, so that remote objects can be manipulated as if they were local.